# OpenVPN only works internal

Tags: linux, openvpn

I have set up a OpenVPN server according to [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-16-04) guide from DigitalOcean. But unfortunately I cannot get it working.

It seems like OpenVPN is just not receiving the network packets. I also tried connecting internally (where the server is the client and the OpenVPN server) and this does work.

To test if OpenVPN even receives the packets I did the following:

- I started openVPN on the command line with verbosity level 11
- I started TCPdump listening to port 1194

When I try to connect with OpenVPN TCPdump shows the request:

```
knarf@harambe:~$ sudo tcpdump -i ens3 port 1194 -n
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on ens3, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
18:27:41.944116 IP [home-ip].52173 > [server-ip].1194: UDP, length 54
18:27:43.114364 IP [home-ip].52173 > [server-ip].1194: UDP, length 54
18:27:47.775198 IP [home-ip].52173 > [server-ip].1194: UDP, length 54
```

Meanwhile OpenVPS is only showing this: (every 10 seconds)

```
Sun Dec 17 18:27:46 2017 us=75680  event_wait returned 0
Sun Dec 17 18:27:46 2017 us=75728 I/O WAIT status=0x0020
Sun Dec 17 18:27:46 2017 us=75739 MULTI: REAP range 240 -> 256
Sun Dec 17 18:27:46 2017 us=75749 SCHEDULE: schedule_find_least NULL
Sun Dec 17 18:27:46 2017 us=75765 PO_CTL rwflags=0x0001 ev=5 arg=0x56369edf31a0
Sun Dec 17 18:27:46 2017 us=75773 PO_CTL rwflags=0x0001 ev=6 arg=0x56369edf3068
Sun Dec 17 18:27:46 2017 us=75784 I/O WAIT TR|Tw|SR|Sw [10/0]
```

After 60 seconds the client gives me the following error:

```
TLS handshake failed. TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
```

Suspecting the firewall is not configured correctly I also disabled UFW but this does not resolve the problem.

I am currently out of ideas of what might cause this problem. I have the following OpenVPN configuration:

```
knarf@harambe:/etc/openvpn$ cat /etc/openvpn/server.conf | grep -vE "\#|;|^$"
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server-harambe.crt
dh dh2048.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth ta.key 0
key-direction 0
auth SHA256
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

and the client:

```
knarf@knarf-XPS13:~$ cat ~/vpn/xps-13.ovpn | grep -vE "\#|;|^$"
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote [server-ip] 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
comp-lzo
verb 3
cipher AES-128-CBC
auth SHA256
key-direction 1
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

I hope someone can spot what is wrong with the current setup.

Comment: Your client configuration is missing.

Comment: Have you tried to run `tcpdump` on server?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I added the client config. @AlexanderTolkachev the `tcpdump` shown is from the server.

Answer (score 0):

In your server configuration is missing part with tls, something like:

```
 tls-auth ta.key 0 # This file is secret
 key-direction 0
```

Comment: The server config file actually contains this line but it was not shown because of the supplied command. I added it to my original post.

Comment: Maybe this also only misses here, but in the server configuration file you don't have cipher `cipher AES-128-CBC`.  And your server.key is not in the configuration file, but I believe this misses only because of your command.